# Navigating to my project in Google APIs Console

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create a android project that uses google maps.
toget a access togoogle maps, i need to obtain a Google Maps API key.

in 
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key
is written : "Navigate to your project in the Google APIs Console."
i went into Google APIs Console, but i dont see there my project name.
the only project there is "API Project".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Project is the default project that is created for you. You could use that project, but instead you should create a new project named after whatever app you're making, and generate the Maps API key etc for the new project.

I believe if you navigate here you should see a button to create a new project:
https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0